# A periodic decimal expansion sequence

Tags: real-analysis, decimal-expansion

This is from my analysis homework.

Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence with the following terms.
$$x_1 = 0,1$$
$$x_2 = 0,13$$
$$x_3 = 0,131$$
$$x_4 = 0,1313$$
$$x_5 = 0,13131$$

and son on. Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \frac{13}{99}$.

My solution is based in two claims (easy to prove by induction). The first one is

$$ 0 \leq x_n - x_{n-2} \leq \frac{1}{10^{n-2}}$$, for $n \geq 3$. And second one is
$$100 x_n = 13 + x_{n-2}$$, for $n \geq 3$.

Now we proof using the limit definition. Consider $\varepsilon > 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{10^n} = 0$, exists a natural number $N$, such that, $$\frac{1}{10^n} < 99 \varepsilon$$ if $n \geq N$. So, if $n \geq \text{max}\{N,3 \}$ we have

$$ 0 \leq x_n - x_{n-2} \leq \frac{1}{10^n}< 99 \varepsilon$$
$$ |x_n - x_{n-2}| < 99 \varepsilon$$
$$ |x_n - (100 x_n - 13) | < 99 \varepsilon$$
$$ |-99 x_n + 13) | < 99 \varepsilon$$
$$ |99 x_n - 13| < 99 \varepsilon$$
$$ | x_n - \frac{13}{99} | < \varepsilon$$

My question is if there exists a more simple solution because this homework is based on only limit definition, so it can be solved without using "advanced" theorems.

Comment: Is it obvious that $-10^{-n}<x_n - \frac{13}{99} < 0$ ? So choose $N > -\log_{10}( \varepsilon)$

Comment: From your observation that $100 x_n = 13 + x_{n-2}$, you  can conclude from standard theorems about limits that $100 x = 13  + x$ (where $x_n \to x$ as $x \to \infty$). What you want then follows from algebra, without any more $\epsilon$-$N$ reasoning.

Comment: @RobArthan in order to use the limit algebra that you mention first I have to proof that the sequence is convergent. I don't know if is easier that way. Thanks for. your comment

Comment: @Henry  I think that the problem is how I a compute $x_n - \frac{13}{99}$ in order to prove that. Thank for your comment

Comment: Yes, I agree you need to prove convergence first. I was just saying that standard theorems get you from your second claim to the answer with just algebra.

Comment: I think I understand the question better now. Your proof is probably fine at a glance, although I haven't gone over it with a fine-toothed comb. Would you accept a proof of the sequence being Cauchy, and then quoting "Cauchy implies convergent"?

Comment: @AdamRubinson, in my course  we have not already cover the Cauchy definition and the Cauchy convergence theorem.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with an independent proof that $\frac{13}{99} = 0.\overset{\mbox{.}}{1}\overset{\mbox{.}}{3} :$

Let $\ x=0.\overset{\mbox{.}}{1}\overset{\mbox{.}}{3}.$

Then $100x = 13.\overset{\mbox{.}}{1}\overset{\mbox{.}}{3}$

$99x = 100x-x = 13.\overset{\mbox{.}}{1}\overset{\mbox{.}}{3} - 0.\overset{\mbox{.}}{1}\overset{\mbox{.}}{3} = 13$

$x = \frac{13}{99} = 0.\overset{\mbox{.}}{1}\overset{\mbox{.}}{3}.$

$$$$

$\frac{13}{99} = 0.\overset{\mbox{.}}{1}\overset{\mbox{.}}{3}=0.13131313\ldots\ .$

Hence for all natural numbers $k$, we have: $\ 0<\frac{13}{99} - x_k < \frac{1}{10^k}. $

Take limits as $k\to \infty$ of the above inequality and quote the Squeeze Theorem.

An alternative method would be to prove that the sequence is Cauchy which is similar to the above method in fact, and then use the fact that every real Cauchy sequence (with the usual metric) is convergent.

Comment: $0,131313...$ is just the sequence $x_n$ that I presented, so it seems like you are proving the result assuming that it is true.

Comment: You can show that $\frac{13}{99} = 0.\overset{\mbox{.}}{1}\overset{\mbox{.}}{3}=0.13131313\ldots\ $ independently by using algebraic methods, or just by using short division algorithm.

Comment: I think if you do that you will define the sequence $x_n$ that I presented

Comment: So you're saying what? that I'm not allowed to assume that $0.\overset{\mbox{.}}{1}\overset{\mbox{.}}{3}$ is a real number? Or I'm allowed to assume it is a real number but not a rational number? Or what?

Comment: What is the meaning of " $0,131313...$"? What mean " $...$"? Is a mathematical object?. The thing is that $0,131313...$ is a sequence (which is the same as the one I presented). In my course, we prove that every real number has a decimal expansion (understood as sequence), I think that the spirit of the problem is to prove that the sequence $x_n$ is the sequence which describes the decimal expansion of 13/99.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, if $n\in\Bbb N$\begin{align}x_{2n}&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{13}{100^k}\\&=\frac{13}{100}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac1{100}\right)^k\\&=\frac{13}{100}\frac{1-\left(\frac1{100}\right)^n}{1-\frac1{100}}\\&=13\frac{1-\left(\frac1{100}\right)^n}{99}.\end{align}Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think that only helps to show $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{2n} = 13/99$, so then I need to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{2n} = lim_{n \to \infty} x_{2n-1}$, and I don't know if is easier that way. As I said, this homework is based only in limit definition. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: It was not a comment; it was an answer. And, since $x_{2n+1}-x_{2n}=10^{-2n-1}$, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{2n}=\frac{13}{99}$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\frac{13}{99}$.

Comment: I recognize that is a valid solution. But in my class we didn't cover theorems like the unicity of the limit, algebra of limits, etc; we only cover the limit definition and I think that in your solution is there a middle step where you need the theorem about sum of limits o you will have to prove it for that particular case.

Comment: That is false. My proof requires only the definition of limit, without any auxiliary theorem concerning limits.